# Calling an overrided method through child's object in main() method

Tags: java, inheritance

I have two classes A and B. 'A' consists of a method map() which is overridden in class B. And  In the main class, I'm creating an object for class 'B'. And I want to call map() of class 'A'. Is there any way to achieve this??

I've tried using a super keyword, but it didn't work.

```
class Parent { 
    void Print() { 
        System.out.println("parent class"); 
    } 
} 

class subclass1 extends Parent {
    @Override   
    void Print() 
    { 
        System.out.println("subclass1"); 
    } 
}
public class Example1 { 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        Parent a;
        a = new subclass1(); 
        a.Print();
        super(a).Print();
    } 
}
```

Comment: No, you don't? Under the rules of object oriented programming, if `B` has its own implementation for the `map` method, _that's what `map` is supposed to do for that object type_. So the real question is "_why_ do you think you need to call the superclass `map`?" (e.g. your code shows off a failed attempt with a different function, so that tells us nothing about what you're actually trying to achieve on a higher level) because in metaphorical terms it sounds like you're trying to go against the flow, rather than with it.

Comment: `A.map()` can only be called from within `B`, using `super.map()`. If you want to call `A.map()` you must create an instance of `A` using `new A()`.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible in Java. If you want to call overridden methods of `Parent`, you have to instantiate `Parent`. Unless you are able to modify `Subclass1`, then you could introduce a new method which calls the parent method.

```java
public class Subclass1 extends Parent {
    public void printParent() {
        super.print();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So there are quite a few things going on here:

First, I should point out that you're not following Java naming conventions, you should probably look into that.

Second, what you want cannot be done and `super(a).print();` is syntactically incorrect.

You could in Subclass1 call the parent like this:

```
class Subclass1 extends Parent {

    @Override   
    void print() { 
        super().print();
        System.out.println("subclass1"); 
    } 
}
```

Then it would print both strings however.

If you wanted only the behaviour of the parent you could just instantiate it directly since it's not abstract:

```
public class Example1 { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Parent a = new Parent(); 
        a.print();
    } 
}
```

Comment: `super()` calls the super constructor (which is not possible there). You mean `super.print()`.